# Python - Modulus between two values

Tags: python, arrays, list, modulo, pi

I have a list of values of theta that is output by the `solve_ivp` function
I need to get all the values in-between `(-pi, pi)` and have been told to use `%` to do so
I understand that `list%pi` will put all values between `0` and `pi`, but how do I do this for between `-pi` and `pi`?

Help greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator does not work this way. It gives you the reminder of division. You can only apply it to two numbers. What you want is probably something like this:

```
import math
pi = math.pi

filtered_list = [x for x in list if -pi < x < pi]
```

Also do not name you list a "list". This is name of class `list`. You do not want to overwrite this!

Answer (score 0):

The python Modulo `%` operator will return a positive number if the divisor is positive.

So

```
pi = 3  # Engineer's pi
x=6.1
y = x % pi  # gives 0.1 (ish)
z = -x % pi # gives 2.9 (ish)
```

you could multiply pi by your input's sign:

```
from numpy import sign
pi = 3  # close enough
x = -6.1
y = x % pi*sign(x)  # gives -2.9 (ish)
```

As such y will always be in the range -pi to pi